# Do new professors typically get paid for course prep done prior to starting their job?

Tags: teaching

I will be starting as an Assistant Professor this fall (in the US). My official start date is one week before the start of classes. This means I will need to develop the course during the summer, before I have officially started my position. I asked the department if there was compensation for class prep, and they said there was not because it is included in my job requirements.

Q: Is this the standard for new professors in the US?

I think it's a little odd, as I'm currently working a full-time job and developing a course on top of that will take substantial effort. If I were being paid for class prep, I could leave my current position earlier. I'm not suggesting that I should be paid for subsequent course preps, but I have never been asked to put so much effort into a job before officially starting the position.

I don't hold it against the department-- I don't think they have anything to do with this decision. I would just like to know if this is typical or not.

Comment: Are you being asked to develop a new course, or teach one?

Comment: So for the first year, you get paid, but for each subsequent year, you have to pay back that same amount.

Comment: Are you really being asked to develop a brand new module in a week, having never taught before?  At my uni that would have needed a process of quality assurance and approval and this wouldn't have been possible.

Comment: I don't get paid for course prep. Luckily my department chair understands that means I prefer to teach courses I've taught before.

Comment: A student's perspective: I've often seen that a prof did not prepare the entire course, but only the first introductory chapters. This implied that the final lecture notes were available only at the and of lecture time, but, in reality, it did not impact much our possibilities to prepare for class.

Comment: Additionally, I should mention that this strategy led to a quantity of content which was well-adapted to the lecture time.

Answer (score 30):

It's also my understanding that your situation is standard.

Basically, you're expected to know how to teach that class already.  Any prep you do before hand amounts to you getting ready to do the job they hired you for, which a normal private sector company doesn't pay you for either.

But really, the explanation doesn't matter so much as the fact that this is widely accepted as normal.

Comment: Your first sentence needs work. Paying is standard or not paying is standard? Also the last: "this" is widely accepted. It is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: I have to strongly contend the "which a normal private sector company doesn't pay you for either". In the private sector it's absolutely normal that the first weeks or even months on the job are getting you ready for whatever you need to do. My very first job ever would always start with giving each new employee 3 books on a specific technology they used and telling the employee "let us know when you're done". Even more importantly in the private sector in a lot of countries you *have to* pay someone for work (as this isn't overtime or freelancing), so minimum wage rules would apply. (cont.)

Comment: Obviously it does have to do with what the job requirements (not job description) asked for, what prior experiences you have, and how the candidate presented themselves. Assuming the candidate presented themselves truthfully then any work they need to do for their employer is paid for by the employer. No gray area.

Comment: @DavidMulder: he is hired to give a course on a topic they already know (if my understanding is correct). Not to learn anything specific to the job. If someone hired to code in Go would happen to never have seen Go code that would be very bad. If someone hired **because he has experience in coding, not specifically with Go** would be hired to code in Go, then yes - they would need time to learn.

Comment: But the time needed to prepare a course is not about learning the material, it's about preparing the course. I don't see how that's similar.

Comment: @WoJ That's why I said "Assuming the candidate presented themselves truthfully". If a company is looking for Go developers and you apply and tell them "I have 10 years of experience developing C applications, but no professional experience with Go" then you will be learning on the job, not before the job.

Comment: @WoJ You are describing a wrong analogy. The issue is not to learn Go, but that he has to write Go code for the new employer before he gets paid. Knowing the topic / Go was the job requirement, preparing a course / writing the code is what he is paid for.

Comment: When you're hired to teach a class, you're expected to already be ready to teach that class.  Full stop.  There's no sense debating the one line I (apparently shouldn't have) added comparing it to the private sector.  It's only tangentially related to the question, and my answer.

Comment: @usr1234567: his job is to teach [something]. It means he comes in and teaches [something]. Like the developer who comes in and starts, from day 1, to code. The dev prepared for that before (on a previous job, because he is passionate, whatever) and has the "materials" ready.

Comment: It's disappointing that this is the case. While it seems fine to expect a professor has the domain and pedagogical experience to teach a course, actually preparing slides, setting up course websites, assignments, etc. don't really seem like they should be on the prof's personal time, especially if the university will claim ownership on whatever you produce.

Answer (score 15):

Aside from the practical issue of it being the universal (US, at least) standard to not pay new professors extra for prep time, it’s also logical not to treat this as a “new professor” issue, for the simple reason that the same issue also affects “old” professors. You will be asked many times over your career to teach classes you haven’t taught before. The fact that you’ll need to work a bit harder to prepare materials when that happens is factored into the job expectations, and the compensation for the work is factored into the normal pay structure. Thus, your idea of a special payment for new professors doesn’t make logical sense.

And speaking of things that are factored in, the assumption that you are a person who actually enjoys (or at least takes it in stride) having to delve into a new subject and prepare materials for a new class is factored into the department’s decision when hiring a new faculty member...

Congrats on the job, and good luck with the class! One week sounds like plenty of time to get ready for the first lecture. I’m sure you’ll do fine.

Comment: "One week sounds like plenty of time to get ready for the first lecture." One week does not sound like anywhere near enough time to come up with a plan on the content of thirteen weeks of lectures and tutorials, assessments and their criteria sheets, and then get the department to approve all of the above.

Comment: @nick012000 well, it all depends I suppose. At my department I don’t need to get anything approved by anyone, and I don’t write all the assessments or lecture material in advance of the semester starting, so one full week of work would be plenty. YMMV. And if one week were not enough, OP would indeed have to work on the course before the official start date of the job, but that doesn’t change the validity of the rest of what I wrote.

Comment: "I don't need to get anything approved by anyone" How do you calibrate assessments and perform moderation if you're not talking to the other staff about assessments? Is your university okay with one professor's "A" being another's "B"?

Comment: @nick012000 yeah, I guess you could say they are okay with it, to use somewhat imprecise language (although there is a small amount of pressure to conform to a reasonable grade distribution, to address your “A” versus “B” issue). And moreover I think this attitude is very common for US college-level mathematics instruction. Different instructors can be teaching the same course using different textbooks or generally different approaches, so coordinating doesn’t always make sense.

Comment: @nick012000 "one week sounds like plenty of time to get ready for the **first** lecture" so why did you change it to one week to prep for 13 weeks?

Comment: @SolarMike Because half of a week 1 lecture is a summary of what you’re going to be doing this semester, how the assessment will be structured, who the teaching staff will be, fire evacuation plans, etc.

Comment: @nick012000 Why on earth would you spent class time going over fire evacuation plans?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft You can’t assume that students have had classes in that building before, or that they can remember the fire evacuation procedures for it if they have.

Comment: @nick Can I assume that they are adults who are capabable of being responsible for their own safety?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Probably, but I’m guessing there’s probably legal liability issues for the university if it’s skipped.

Comment: Even for a subject I know back to front and inside out (which is only a small fraction of what I teach) it takes me about 16 hours or two full working days to prepare a lecture the first time I give it. For a course that has three lectures a week, that's over a week already. It would also be kind of useful to have decided at least what the syllabus was  before starting to teach. Add in that a new hire will have to spend time finding their office and their lecture theatre, doing inductions and safety training etc and a week is really pushing it.

Answer (score 6):

I've been a professor at three universities (one private university and two state universities), and none offered me summer pay for course preps before the start of my position. For my most recent position, I spent three months developing three new courses while also working another job full-time (which meant working from 8am-11pm every day Monday-Sunday), so I understand why you are asking. But, again, my own experiences tell me this is standard practice. (By the way, I absolutely love teaching. But loving what you do doesn't mean you're not allowed to occasionally get irritated when you're expected to do that thing for a new job for 3 months with no pay.)

Answer (score 4):

I doubt you could expect to be paid for anything prior to formally starting your position and there might be rules that forbid it, especially in, say, a State University in the US.

But, if I were the department chair, and I was very happy to have "caught" you as a new professor, I'd try to find some pot of money to give you a few silver pieces to make you happy as a clam as your first experience. I might fail at that, but I'd try.

I hope, at least, that they are working to make your entrance a happy and easy one otherwise. But all funds expended need to be accounted for and if you aren't actually on the payroll it is a hard game.

Some faculty get an initial grant of funds to get things going - mostly research -, but none of that happens until you are on board.

Answer (score 4):

Payment for something like this is sometimes done; if you negotiate for it when accepting your position.  From what I have seen in the US, it is somewhat common to be offered summer support (in terms of salary) without having any teaching responsibilities for some of the months leading up to your first semester, and/or to have a reduced teaching load during your first semesters to account for this. But this is something you need to ask for before you sign your contract.

Once you have agreed to take the position, there is 1. little motivation for the university to offer this to you, and 2. (probably more importantly) much less possibility of there actually being some money available to the college/department to be used for this purpose.

Comment: I think this is a misleading answer. Summer support, while indeed common, is never framed as payment for “course prep” as far as I know, so it’s not “payment for something like this”, and doesn’t fit what OP is asking about. Similarly for the mention of teaching reductions.

Comment: I agree with the answer, I was paid a bit to prepare material - first time in post so no material to fall back on... So they made an exception ie being nice... But it all depends on the department and the budget...

Answer (score 0):

As a counterpoint to the other answers: yes, you will be paid for that time. But not today. You will be paid when closing in on retirement / job change. During your last semester at the university, you will not be asked to prepare a course for the next year. But you don't expect your salary to drop accordingly at that time to account for that, do you? Your salary is simply differed to that moment if you really want to know what and when you are paid for discrete tasks. In fact, your salary will certainly even be higher when you near retirement than it is today, so you can rejoice in the fact that you are paid extra for that prep time.

Answer (score 0):

**Employees are paid from their contractual start date, employers don't expect work before this date.**

> <sup>My official start date is one week before the start of classes. This means I will need to develop the course during the summer...I asked the department
> if there was compensation for class prep, and they said there was not
> because it is included in my job requirements.</sup>

<sup>Your employer doesn't anticipate a need for course development before you start, you needn't work during the summer; the department expects you to prepare your classes once you've started, for which you will be compensated.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is utterly standard in the US.  I’m not going to try to make any arguments for why, you’re probably right that it’s unfair, but it doesn’t matter because it’s how it is.

One thing that is common at top universities is to give new faculty one fewer course in their first year in recognition of the fact that they’re likely to be doing more prep than returning faculty.